# How to filter a HMS time variable in R

Tags: r, filtering

I have a time variable (time) class = "hms" "difftime" and would like to filter the column to only contains observations that were after 00:00:15 (15 seconds)

**Example**

**Current Data**

```
X | Time 
A | 00:00:05
B | 00:10:04
C | 00:05:03
D | 00:00:03
E | 00:15:04
F | 00:15:03
```

**Desired output**

```
X | Time   
B | 00:10:04
C | 00:05:03
E | 00:15:04
F | 00:15:03
```

Answer (score 0):

`hms` stores duration in seconds :

```
as.numeric(hms::hms(seconds = 1 , minutes = 1, hours = 1))
[1] 3661
```

You could just compare your `hms` data to 15 to get observations above 15s:

```
data <- hms::hms(1:20,0*(1:20),0*(1:20))
data[data>15]
00:00:16
00:00:17
00:00:18
00:00:19
00:00:20
```